# How to get startTime and endTime using Mysql and Java (Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following table in mysql:

```
id              Day                hourStart           hourEnd
 1           2015-01-01            00:00:00            23:59:00
 2           2015-01-05            10:00:00            10:20:00
 3           2015-01-05            10:20:00            10:30:00
 4           2015-01-05            10:30:00            10:40:00
```

Follow the image of the my table:

[image: folow the image]

My doubts is, How to can I get the hourStart and hourEnd in my java code? Because I try get the hour info, but I can see this information

```
 "hourEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00-03:00",
 "hourStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00-03:00",

 "hourEnd":"1970-01-01T10:10:00-03:00",
 "hourStart":"1970-01-01T10:00:00-03:00",
```

I need understand how can I remove the 1970-01-01T and -03:00 and keep only 10:00 and 10:10??

follow Consulta.class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="consulta")
 @XmlRootElement(name = "consulta")
 public class Consulta {

         @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private Date dia;
        private Date horaInicio;
        private Date horaFinal;


     ...gets/sets HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should make your variables `LocalTime`. Joda date inclues all information ( year, month, day, time and timezone ).

```
private LocalTime horaInicio;
private LocalTime horaFinal;
```

So if you need to store only the time of the dat `LocalTime` is your best bet. See [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) the documentation.